# openSUSE, where do QFiles get saved?

Tags: c++, qt5, opensuse, qfile

Okay, so this might sound super trivial but I am completely stumped. My final goal is to write into a .xlsx file or a .csv file but for starters I thought I would try to open or create a simple .txt file in qt with QFile, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 MainWindow w;

 QString filename = "test.txt";
 QFile file(filename);
 
 if(file.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QFile::Text)){
  QTextStream stream(&file);
  stream << "something" << endl;
 }else{
  qDebug() << "file open error";
 }

 w.show();
 return a.exec();
}
```

With this try I tried both possibilities, at first I didn't create the .txt file and let the program create one, which didn't throw an error and also didn't go into the `else` case. Secondly I also tried to open the same file because now it is supposedly created and again, no errors and no problems. Now I wanted to check whether my code worked and I looked for my .txt file but I couldn't find it. From what I gathered on the internet, it should have been in the root directory but it wasn't.

Afterwards I decided to also specify the path to be the path of my application, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 MainWindow w;

 QString filename = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "test.txt";
 QFile file(filename);
 
 if(file.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QFile::Text)){
  QTextStream stream(&file);
  stream << "something" << endl;
 }else{
  qDebug() << "file open error";
 }

 w.show();
 return a.exec();
}
```

Same result, no errors and can't find the file anywhere. I also tried `QApplication::applicationFilePath()` but this brought me to the `else` case.

So what I am asking for is where are my files getting saved to or how can I define the file path in a way that works. I am using Qt 5.12.7 and openSUSE Leap 15.2, any solution is greaty appreciated.

**Update:**
I played around a bit, no success of finding the file itself but I am sure now that they exist after the program exits and that they are saved properly because I can read from them properly and also access them from other projects then the one I created them in, so they are definitely not saved in the project directory.

Comment: The file should be in the built folder, at least that's the case for me using Windows 10

Comment: Thanks for you answer but my build folder only consits of moc and .o files. Is that the folder you meant?

Comment: What's `filename`?  If it's an absolute path then the file will be created with that absolute path.  If it's a relative path then the file will be created at that path relative to the executable's current working directory.  The behaviour is the same as for e.g.`std::ofstream` -- it's not specific to `QFile`.

Comment: I would want it to be a relative path, which I thought I did with my first try. I just want the file to be in the directory of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths starts from "current working directory", process creator is responsible for assigning it to some specific path, for example when you run your application from qtcreator it assigns `cwd` according to run configuration, you can edit run configuration on projects tab.

If you don't want to depend on `cwd` just use executable dir as base to you path `QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath()).filePath("test.txt")`

Comment: Okay, so I did what you suggested but as I said, I tried this before. I even printed the result of your command and it was `/opt/sqlTest/bin/test.txt` , "sqlTest" is the name of my project. Now correct me if I am wrong but the opt folder in question is the one in the root directory but that is empty. The file isn't in the build directory and as well as it's not in the regular project folder with all the .cpp and .h file.

Comment: If you can access it and read it, as you said, file must be there. Do you see it in terminal? `ls -la /opt/sqlTest/bin/test.txt`, maybe your file browser have problems accessing directory or showing files?

Comment: nope, I typed in your command in the terminal and I got the error file or directory not found

Comment: Do you use apparmor or any other sandboxing utility?

Comment: I am using apparmor, yes, is that a problem?

Comment: I dont know much about apparmor but I guess it could prevent the process from creating files or run process from chroot.

Comment: Well I guess I will do some research and get back here once I find an answer.

Comment: Okay so looked in the internet, couldn't find anything similar. I also played around a bit with the settings of apparmor and even disabled it but it didn't change anything. I did however find out I can access these created files from accross projects, so it's not even constrained in that sense.